# CSS width value to respect embedded content's (iframe, object, embed) width attribute

Tags: css, iframe, width, overriding

i'm using a grid based layout, which, in short, looks like this:

```
<div class="width-2">
    <h1>300px</h1>
    <div class="embed-container">
        <iframe width="400" height="400" ...></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

The appropriate CSS:

```
h1 { width: 300px; }
.width-2 { width: 600px; }
.embed-container > iframe { width: 100%; /* Must turn out to be 600px wide */ }
```

The problem starts when i want to introduce `auto` width:

```
<div class="width-auto">
    <h1>300px</h1>
    <div class="embed-container">
        <iframe width="400" height="400" ...></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

With css:

```
h1 { width: 300px; }
.width-2 { width: 600px; }

.embed-container > iframe { 
    width: 100%; 
} 
.width-auto .embed-container > iframe { 
    width: auto; /* Must revert to 400px, but doesn't? */ 
}
```

What i expect is that iframe would go back to take its width from its own `width` attribute and be 400 pixels wide, but instead it is 300px wide!!!

Here it is live:
http://jsfiddle.net/ETUkD/2/

Note that what is represented by iframe here is any embedded content, so i don't want to regex additional style attribute on it, or modify it in any other way.

**UPDATE**: One solution is to use `:not()` selector, but that is not supported by internet explorer...

```
div:not(.width-auto) > .embed-container > iframe { 
    width: 100%; 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution 1:**
You could consider using Selectivzr. http://selectivizr.com/ It will allow you to use :not() in IE6-8 using one of many javascript libraries.

**Solution 2:** Why not be more specific in your CSS like this? http://jsfiddle.net/pkY8K/

```
.width-2 .embed-container iframe {
    width: 100%;   
}
```

Declare the iframe width to be 100% only when it's in the div's you know need it. And then drop the `.width-auto .embed-container iframe { width: auto; }` entirely.

Comment: thanx for your answer! solution 2 is good, but i guess, i didn't mention that i have .width-1 until .width-14 selectors — i'm looking for a more universal solution.

Comment: There's many ways you could tackle that. You could give every div that is NOT `width:auto` an additional class in your HTML like `class="grid"`. And then do `.grid .embed-container iframe { width:100%; }` This way you would have to add more classes to all your div's in the HTML, but you wouldn't be doing so much work in the CSS.

Comment: Yet another way to do this would be to rename all of your `.width-#` classes in your HTML to have a prefix of `grid-` like this: `.grid-width-#` and leave `.width-auto` alone. Then use `div[class*=grid-width] > .embed-container > iframe { width:100%; }` to target them all. I believe this works in IE7 and up.